# I get an error when I use the code "imageCapture.takePicture" of CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I get the error

> "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.util.List
>   androidx.camera.core.SessionConfig$Builder.getSingleCameraCaptureCallbacks()'
>   on a null object reference"

when I use the code below:

```
 val file = File(externalMediaDirs.first(),"${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")
        imageCapture.takePicture(file,executor,object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener{
            override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                val msg = "success: ${file.absolutePath}"
                Log.d("CameraXApp", msg)
                viewFinder.post {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onError(
                imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError,
                message: String,
                cause: Throwable?
            ) {
                val msg = "failed: $message"
                Log.e("CameraXApp", msg, cause)
                viewFinder.post {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        })
```

Is there a callback that I haven't setted?

Comment: If you haven't yet figured it out, check if you needed to bind the CameraX life cycle. Typically, at the end, include "        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)
"

Comment: Thanks,you are right.I didn't bind hte lifecycle of CameraX

Comment: where exactly i have to bind the   lifecycle of CameraX ??

Comment: It's at the last line of method "startCamera",like "CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture)", "imageCapture" is the instance of ImageCapture@SideegMoHammed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below code to initialize imageCapture

imageCapture=ImageCapture.Builder().build()

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
this, cameraSelector, preview,imageCapture)